# Set form control to untouched on focus using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive

In my form, I would like to set form controls as untouched when the user focuses on them in order to hide the validation messages which are displayed when the field is touched and invalid.

How can I do this?

I have tried writing a directive but have been unable to get it to work. I can see in the console that the value in the directive is changing from true to false but the form control doesn't update.

**HTML:**

```
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid)" novalidate="">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name*</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" untouch="userForm.name" />
      <h3>Touched: {{userForm.name.$touched}}</h3>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**Directive:**

```
validationApp.directive('untouch', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            untouch : '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.bind('focus', function() {
                console.log(scope.untouch.$touched);
                scope.untouch.$setUntouched();
                console.log(scope.untouch.$touched);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oy9YNyaRzh13XHghIUk9?p=preview)

Comment: resetting something to untouched when it gets touched doesn't sound right. Why not use the $dirty flag instead to decide whether to show or hide validation messages?

Comment: My validation errors are shown when the field is invalid and touched. If it were dirty instead of touched the error would show as the user is typing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the *required* `ngModel` controller

```
.directive('untouch', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, modelCtrl) {
            element.on('focus', function() {
                modelCtrl.$setUntouched();
                scope.$apply(); // just note, dfsq pointed this out first
            });
        }
    };
});
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/An6qCrc9Nt4itTeDqv9K?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: You do not need a directive to accomplish this.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/34099296/404699

Comment: @steampowered nice

Answer (score 6):

You can make the control untouched easily when the control gains focus by adding one attribute to the html - no new directives required.  Simply add

```
ng-focus="userForm.name.$setUntouched()"
```

and you have

```
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid)" novalidate="">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name*</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" 
          ng-focus="userForm.name.$setUntouched()" />
      <h3>Touched: {{userForm.name.$touched}}</h3>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Also, you might consider a better name for your control than "name".

Answer (score 2):

You just need to apply scope changes, because `element.bind` won't trigger digest by itself:

```
validationApp.directive('untouch', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            untouch: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.bind('focus', function() {
                scope.untouch.$setUntouched();
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/fgtpi7ecA34VdxZjoaZQ?p=preview

Comment: Doh! Forgot about that bit in my answer :( +1