# Ionic item-select flashes on android after losing focus on a text item-input

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, validation, ionic-framework

*Running through `ionic serve` works fine.*

*When running on a device*, after page loaded and after you either typed or just selected the text box. Then when you select the "select (dropdown)", the dropdown options flashes and then it does not accept any input (just closes without selecting), however if you try again it works.

As far as I can tell it is due to the `ng-untouched` being replaced with `ng-touched`

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item class="item-divider">
        <b class="">New member's details</b>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="item-input">
        <label class="input-label" for="firstName">First name</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="memberDetails.firstName" name="firstName" id="firstName" ng-class="{'input-validation-error' : applicationForm.firstName.$error.required && (applicationForm.firstName.$touched || showRequired)}" required />
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="item-input">
        <label class="input-label" for="surname">Surname</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="memberDetails.surname" name="surname" id="surname" ng-class="{'input-validation-error' : applicationForm.surname.$error.required && (applicationForm.surname.$touched || showRequired)}" required />
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="item-input">
        <label class="input-label" for="initials">Initials</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="memberDetails.initials" name="initials" id="initials" ng-class="{'input-validation-error' : applicationForm.initials.$error.required && (applicationForm.initials.$touched || showRequired)}" required />
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="item-input item-select">
        <label class="input-label" for="title">Title</label>
        <select ng-model="memberDetails.titleId" ng-options="lookup.id as lookup.description for lookup in titleLookup" name="title" id="title" ng-class="{'input-validation-error' : applicationForm.title.$error.required && (applicationForm.title.$touched || showRequired)}" required></select>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Is there any work around or fix for this issue?

**EDIT**

The problem seems to be related to angularjs on android, the problem seems to appear on an angularjs site from a android chrome browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a work around, based on [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365914/set-form-control-to-untouched-on-focus-using-angularjs)

Just add this directive to your app:

```
.directive('input', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, modelCtrl) {
            if (attr.type === "text" && attr.name && modelCtrl) {
                element.on('focus', function () {
                    modelCtrl.$setTouched();
                    scope.$apply();
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

**Note:** the problem doesn't occur on all devices just on some, (Haven't found the root of the problem)